# Trying to get data from IOT using PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, iot

I'm trying to get JSON from my IOT application. I can post data to my IOT application so my connection is ok but cant get a response. I only get a not allowed error.

I use this code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$endpoint_url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result === FALSE) {
    printf("cUrl error (#%d): %s<br>\n", curl_errno($ch),
        htmlspecialchars(curl_error($ch)));
}
curl_close($ch);

rewind($verbose);
$verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);

echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "</pre>\n";
```

But all I get back is the following:

```
Verbose information:
* Hostname integrations.thethingsnetwork.org was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 13.69.184.129...
* Connected to integrations.thethingsnetwork.org (13.69.184.129) port 443 
(#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: 
ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*    subject: CN=integrations.thethingsnetwork.org
*    start date: Jan 31 12:04:08 2019 GMT
*    expire date: May  1 12:04:08 2019 GMT
*    subjectAltName: integrations.thethingsnetwork.org matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /ttn-eu/api/v2/down/secret/test?key=secret HTTP/1.1
Host: integrations.thethingsnetwork.org
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Server: nginx/1.13.7
< Date: Wed, 20 Mar 2019 15:33:10 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host integrations.thethingsnetwork.org left intact
```

How can I get the data?

Comment: `405 Method Not Allowed` You're performing a GET and the server is telling you that you can't do that. Perhaps it requires POST. You'll need to refer to the docs to find out.

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying the Request type in your curl request which automatically defaults it to a `GET` one. Add the following to your code.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');`

Comment: I added it but now I get  HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: Still no luck, keep getting badrequest even If I try GET and PUT

Comment: The bad request could also be the data you pass. Can you debug and output what you are sending? Some requests are sent in the url for example ?parm=1&param2=2 and other are sent in the body of the request in form-data